# How to stop promises loop when using workers

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
let stop = false;

function functionA() {
    return Promise.reject();
}
const processMe = function(label) {
    if (stop) {
      console.log("processMe stop");
      return;
    }
    functionA()
    .then(function() {
        console.log(`${label} then handler`);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        stop = true;
        console.log(`${label} catch handler`);
    });
};

console.log("Starting loop");
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
  if (stop) {
    break;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ 
            processMe(n)
        }, n * 1000);
}
console.log("Loop complete");
```

The code above is not 100% complete. If it runs like it is now it works fine, the problem is when functionA executes a Worker in which Promise.reject() is called, then running this code would lead in:

```
Starting loop
Loop complete
0 catch handler
1 catch handler
2 catch handler
3 catch handler
4 catch handler
...
```

Thus using the "stop" flag wont work.

Comment: _the first time processMe() is called_ you mean functionA() ?

Comment: This code is not valid: `const processMe() = `. It would be better to make a snippet (use the toolbar button in the edit window).

Comment: Can you please post a [reprex]? A promise `.catch()` handler doesn't run when there is an exception, it runs when the promise is rejected.

Comment: It doesn't matter what exactly `functionA` does, as long as it returns a promise that will get rejected when an error occurs. You can achieve that with a worker by sending the error as well. Show us that part of your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior on Chrome is the same as for any other spec-compliant JavaScript engine: If the promise from `functionA` in `processMe` consistently rejects in that loop, then the `catch` handlers being added to it each time will all be called *after* the loop completes. Promise callbacks are guaranteed to occur asynchronously.¹ If `functionA` *itself* throws an exception, since that's synchronous (assuming this isn't in an `async` function), that would synchronously terminate the loop. But not a promise rejection.

Example:

```js
function functionA() {
    return Promise.reject();
}
const processMe = function(label) {
    functionA()
    .then(function() {
        console.log(`${label} then handler`);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`${label} catch handler`);
    });
};

console.log("Starting loop");
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
  processMe(n);
}
console.log("Loop complete");
```

The output there is:

```
Starting loop
Loop complete
0 catch handler
1 catch handler
2 catch handler
```

...and so on, on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and any spec-compliant engine.

---

You've said in a comment that you only want a single `catch` to be triggered. To do that, either:

- Use `Promise.all` if you want the asynchronous operations running in parallel, and have `processMe` return the promise chain (and not use `catch`). Then use `catch` where the loop is.
- Chain the promises on each other if you want the async calls to occur in series (one after another) rather than parallel.

In parallel — note that I gave the last one a 50% chance of failing, so run it a couple of times to see both success and error:

```js
function functionA(n) {
    console.log(`functionA starting ${n}`)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (n === 9 && Math.random() < 0.5) {
                reject(new Error(`error processing ${n}`));
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}
const processMe = function(n) {
    return functionA(n)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(`${n} then handler`);
        return result;
    });
};

console.log("Starting loop");
const promises = [];
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
  promises.push(processMe(n));
}
Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => {
    console.log("All promises completed");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Got rejection: ${error.message}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

In series (1 of 2) (same 50% chance of failure on the last one):

```js
function functionA(n) {
    console.log(`functionA starting ${n}`)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (n === 9 && Math.random() < 0.5) {
                reject(new Error(`error processing ${n}`));
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }, Math.random() * 200);
    });
}
const processMe = function(n) {
    return functionA(n)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(`${n} then handler`);
        return result;
    });
};

console.log("Starting loop");
let promise = Promise.resolve();
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
  promise = promise.then(() => processMe(n));
}
promise
.then(() => {
    console.log("All promises completed");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Got rejection: ${error.message}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

In series (2 of 2): If your loop is looing through an array and you want to do them in series, there's an idiom for this, the "promise `reduce`" idiom. It looks like this (same 50% chance of failure on the last one):

```js
function functionA(n) {
    console.log(`functionA starting ${n}`)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (n === 9 && Math.random() < 0.5) {
                reject(new Error(`error processing ${n}`));
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }, Math.random() * 200);
    });
}
const processMe = function(n) {
    return functionA(n)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(`${n} then handler`);
        return result;
    });
};

console.log("Starting loop");
const theArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const promise = theArray.reduce((p, n) => {
    return p.then(() => processMe(n));
}, Promise.resolve());
promise
.then(() => {
    console.log("All promises completed");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Got rejection: ${error.message}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

¹ Promise completions are [queued to the PromiseJobs queue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions). Because of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics, no jobs from the PromiseJobs queue can be run until the current job (running the loop) completes.

Comment: As I already wrote, the behavior is not the same, I added logs to see it in the console, and I can see that it is as I wrote.

Comment: @David - If you think Chrome is different, it's observational error. The code in the question has a few significant errors. Please correct them and provide a [mcve] of the problem that replicates the behavior you think you're seeing, and we can explain what's going on.

Comment: A citation for this would be good, I can't find anything in the spec which says that a reject can't happen before the function returns. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-constructor

Comment: Ok, I would try to cut out the code from my project.

Comment: @rubenwardy - Updated. :-) Promise completions are [queued to the PromiseJobs queue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions). Because of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics, no jobs from the PromiseJobs queue can be run until the current job (running the loop) completes.

Comment: I updated my question, but it's still not reproducible in this way, I must check the difference.

Comment: Ok, I found out that I had a different code running for Edge than for Chrome, a fallback that is running in a Worker in which case, based on my question's code I'm never seeing console.log("processMe stop"); My intention was to only see " catch handler" once.

Comment: @David - That explains the difference. If you only want to see the catch handler run once, I've updated the answer with a few options for you.